# How to view the report

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

Using VB6 & Crystal Report 9. Need help with the VB6 code.

When i click the button, i want to view the report in the form. Any ideas on how to view the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Crystal Report Viewer Control. Right click toolbox window and select Components...
Then scroll down and select Crystal Report Viewer Control. Place it on a form and create a
method to set path to report file, report parameters etc.

```
Private Sub mShowReport()

    '...set report file...
    CRViewer1.ReportSource = "C:\Reports\MyReport.rpt"
    '...populate report params...
    '*** insert code here ***
    '...show it...
    CRViewer1.ViewReport

End Sub
```